# Kubernetes service can't communicate with each other

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

I'm new with Kubernetes and I tried to create two services that can communicate with each other. The first service is a simple static web (HTML, js) with type `LoadBalancer` and the second service is a express.js backend with the type `ClusterIP`. Here's my `service.yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: number-generator
spec:
  selector:
    app: number-generator
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: number-web
spec:
  selector:
    app: number-web
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  type: LoadBalancer
```

And here's my `deployment.yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: number-generator
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: number-generator
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: number-generator
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: number-generator
        image: cantdocpp/number-generator
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: number-web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: number-web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: number-web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: number-web
        image: cantdocpp/number-web:v5
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

So inside the `number-web` service which can be accessed in `localhost:80`, should access the `number-generator` API to get a random number. I tried to access it using the `http://number-generator/` and `http://number-generator:3000/`, but both of them return a network error like this:

```
GET http://number-generator/ net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

The error should be more or less the same wether I call `http://number-generator/` or `http://number-generator:3000/`. So how can I make this two services talks to each others ?

Comment: Does your request pass when instead of `http://number-generator:3000` you tried `http://number-generator.default.svc.cluster.local:3000` ?

Comment: hi @rkosegi, it's still not working

Answer (score 1):

I just found the problem.

So, because I use a static site for the frontend, when I call the backend service **it actually calls it from the browser**. The browser is not our kubernetes cluster, so when I tried to access the **number-generator** service using **ajax**, it sends those error.

When I tried to change my static frontend into **express app**, it can access the backend **number-generator** service, because it's included in the cluster.